# Where will load fall using Nginx, Varnish, and HAProxy?

Tags: nginx, varnish, haproxy

We are looking into scaling our servers and I am not sure where load will fall as visitor count increases.

I have one HAProxy load balancer, that proxies to two Varnish Nginx static content servers. As our load increases, which server(s) will take the largest hit in terms of resource impact? They are all Digital Ocean droplets so I can scale them up as needed. Would the load be highest on the HAProxy server, or the Varnish servers?

I appreciate any input.

Comment: well the question is why do you think you need scaling? did you face any problems ?

Comment: We run a service that takes a yearly spike in service. The spike only lasts for about a week, before things return to normal. Last year, we could not handle the increased demand and our server configuration completely failed. We see about a 900% increase in traffic over the course of three hours, which leads to large scaling needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience with static content servers, the highest load will be on Nginx. This of course depends on your Varnish VCL setup, as a poorly configured VCL will put increased load on Varnish. However, you shouldn't see load issues on HAProxy for a while.

A well tuned setup with Varnish and Nginx should allow you to server 8000-12000 requests/sec on each box, with a fairly reasonably sized box.

The best solution is to of course have monitoring. I recommend setting up [munin](http://munin-monitoring.org/). It gives you a bunch of graphs and has plugins for nginx, varnish and haproxy. You should monitor each server's CPU and RAM utilization, fork rate, etc. This will give you insight into bottlenecks.

Comment: Thank you very much for this. I am looking into the best practice configuration for NGINX with Varnish. Do you have any specific suggestions on how to tune for a static HTML configuration with Varnish and NGINX?